# What is the difference between silent post URL and relay post URL in authorize.net?

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am integrating Authorize.net gateway with my web application. I am using DPM method. I would like to know the difference between the Silent POST and relay response URL.

I am using the following code :

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"x_relay_response\" value=\"TRUE\"/>\n";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"x_relay_url\" value=\"" . $relay_url ."\"/>\n";
```

However, I am getting the response through POST method on the Silent Post URL ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Silent Post is Authorize.Net's version of Paypal's IPN. Whenever a payment is made, regardless of how it was made, a notification will be sent via Silent Post to notify the merchant of the payment.

Relay Response is their mechanism of allow a merchant who uses a remote form of payment (SIM, DPM, etc) to allow the customer to return back to their website to close out the transaction (e.g. display a receipt page, thank you messages, etc).